# ROC plot for continuous data in R

Tags: r, forecasting, predictive-models, roc

I am currently estimating a bunch of ARMA models, and using them to predict subsets of my data. In order to evaluate their predictive accuracy I would like to make some ROC plots, however since all of my variables are continuous, I wonder how this could be done in R.

Best, Thomas

P.S: I have looked at the ROCR package, but this seems to only work for dichotomous variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that *is* the basis for ROC curves. You see what proportion of correct predictions (i.e. yes or no) are at a variety of predictor levels. The analog of an ROC curve for continuous outcomes would be a validation plot. You develop a prediction score on a training set and validate it on a test set. Or you develop it on the full set and then use bootstrap methods to create neo-samples for validation.

Answer (score 2):

The ROC analysis is for binary data, but the AUC of a ROC is just one case of an ordinal rank effect size that can also be used for continuous predictors, which is referred to as Ruscio's A (2008), or the probability of superiority, or several other names. It's a fully non parametric version of the Common Language Effect Size.

I have an implementation of both this statistic and its bootstrapped 95% CIs in an R package [here](https://github.com/ianhussey/SCED/tree/master/R), where it's labelled Ruscio's A effect.

Also see discussion and other implementations [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/11/calculating-auc.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903092/calculate-auc-in-r).

Finally, if you if you're interested in a full regression framework for ordinal, semi parametric modelling, see the [PIM package (De Neve, 2017)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pim/vignettes/pim.pdf).